# Is there a way to use existing structs as enum variants?

Tags: rust

I'm using an enum for polymorphism, similar to the following:

```
enum MyType {
    Variant1 { a: i32, b: i32 },
    Variant2 { a: bool, b: bool },
}
```

Is there clean way to use existing structs for `Variant1` and `Variant2`? I've done the following:

```
struct Variant1 {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}

struct Variant2 {
    a: bool,
    b: bool,
}

enum MyType {
    Variant1(Variant1),
    Variant2(Variant2),
}
```

but it feels pretty clunky. I was wondering if there's a better way to accomplish a similar thing.

Comment: "enum for polymorphism," ???

Comment: https://keepcalmandlearnrust.com/2017/03/polymorphism-in-rust-enum-vs-trait-struct/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There have been multiple RFCs about making enum variants their own type:

- [RFC 1450: Types for enum variants](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1450)
- [RFC 2593: Enum variant types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2593)

Unfortunately, they have been postponed or not yet decided on as this is not considered a language priority.

This means that right now, the way you have proposed is the only way to have types for enum variants.

Comment: Can the boilerplate be reduced / sugared a little with macros then? Or is it too complicated because they would span accross `enum` *and* `struct` *and* maybe [traits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51567350/3719101) definitions ?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's exactly how that works.